# Is the span of all nilpotent ideals also a nilpotent ideal?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, modules, ideals

Given a non-zero Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$ over $\mathbb{C}$, we define $\mathcal{L}^2 = \big[\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{L} \big] = \big\{ [x, y]: x, y\in \mathcal{L} \big\}$, and for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k\geq 2$, define $\mathcal{L}^{k+1} = \big[ \mathcal{L}, \mathcal{L}^k \big]$. We call $\mathcal{L}$ **nilpotent** if there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^n = \{0\}$, and when $\mathcal{L}$, we call the least $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^n = \{0\}$ the **nil-index** of $\mathcal{L}$. For instance, any abelian Lie algebra is nilpotent and their nil-index is $2$.

Now suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a non-nilpotent and non-zero Lie algebra. Suppose $\mathcal{I}$ is the family of nilpotent two-sided non-trivial ideals in $\mathcal{L}$ is non-empty. Observe that for any $I, J\in \mathcal{I}$, $I+J$ is also an ideal and $(I+J)^3 \subseteq I^2 + J^2$. Since $\mathcal{L}$ is not nilpotent, $I+J$ is also a non-trivial nilpotent ideal. If the nil-index of $I$ is $n$ and the nil-index of $J$ is $m$, then the nil-index of $I+J$ is at most $\max(n, m)+1$.

Put $\mathcal{J} = \operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{C}} \Big( \bigcup_{I\in \mathcal{I}} I\Big)$. Clearly $\mathcal{J}$ is an ideal, although it could be the entire $\mathcal{L}$. My question is: if $\mathcal{J}$ is a proper ideal, is it necessarily nilpotent? If not (i.e. if $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{L}$ or if $\mathcal{J}$ is not nilpotent), can we find a maximal nilpotent ideal in $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: What does $\mathcal J = \mathcal I$ mean, since the left-hand side is an ideal and the right-hand side a collection of ideals? Also, why should properness of $\mathcal J$ matter? If you can prove it for $\mathcal J$ proper, then can't you prove it in general by replacing $\mathcal L$ by, say, $\mathcal L \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2$?

Comment: The answer is yes; the maximal nilpotent ideal is called the [nilradical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilradical_of_a_Lie_algebra) and it is the ideal $\mathcal{J}$ you construct. The adjective "two-sided" is unnecessary for Lie algebra ideals: all one-sided ideals are two-sided. You can also remove the words "non-empty", "non-trivial", "non-zero", "non-nilpotent", and "proper" and everything still works.

Comment: Well, there's an obvious non-finitely generated example where sum of all nilpotent ideals is not nilpotent. Take direct sum of nilpotent Lie algebras $L_k$, $k \in \Bbb N$, such that $L_k$ is $k$-step nilpotent. Throw in a copy of something like a free Lie algebra or $sl_2$ if you want properness. Then $\bigoplus_k L_k$ is not nilpotent, and is equal to the sum of all nilpotent ideals.

Comment: @GrantB. ...The only words you _can not_ remove are the words "finite dimensional" from the link you provided. I'm not so sure if you can get away by only requiring your algebra to be artinian — there's no analogue of Hopkins–Levitzki theorem for lie algebras. Nilradical is, indeed, nilpotent, if it is finitely generated as a Lie (sub)algebra, but it is certainly not always the case.

Comment: It is strange to start the induction at $n=2$: $L^1=L$, $L^{i+1}=[L,L^i]$ is the usual definition. Also, $n$-step nilpotent means that $L^{n+1}=0$, and when $n$ is minimal it is called the nilpotency class. So abelian Lie algebra are the 1-step nilpotent ones. The class really corresponds to the number of strata, which makes alternative definitions a bit confusing.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry for the typo... I mean the case where $\mathcal{J}$ is not proper and fixed the typo.

Comment: @GrantB. Thanks for your hints and I edited the question accordingly. I am mainly blocked by showing that $\mathcal{J}$ is nilpotent when it is not equal to $\mathcal{L}$. In the link you included, it is also mentioned that the (algebraic) sum of two nilpotent ideals is also nilpotent. However, I do not know how to prove that arbitrary sum of nilpotent ideals is still nilpotent, although it might be proved somewhere.

Comment: @Sanae as Denis T indicates, you do need $\mathcal{L}$ to be finite dimensional for the result to be true. In this case any arbitrary sum is equal to a finite subsum, so $\mathcal{J}$ is a finite sum of nilpotent ideals hence nilpotent. Denis gave a counterexample when $\mathcal{L}$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @DenisT In your example $\bigoplus_{k\in \mathbb{N}}L_k$, may I ask if the nilradical can be constructed, or its existence can be proved? In general (as in my second question) when the infinite sum of nilpotent ideals is not nilpotent, can we construct one or prove that it exists?